# Min weight matching in Euclidean 2d space

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, euclidean-geometry

Say you have a graph consisting of $k$ red nodes and $k$ blue nodes in Euclidean $2$-d space. There is an edge between every red-blue pair, and edge weights are distances. Our goal is to find the min-weight matching.

The Hungarian algorithm solves the more general case where the edge weights are arbitrary. Is there a more efficient approach that takes advantage of the Euclidean aspect?

Comment: For instance: http://people.cs.vt.edu/sharathr/sa_stoc12.pdf

Comment: These types of algorithms are extensively studied in theoretical computer science and computational geometry. Unfortunately the “best” runtime case algorithms are typically complicated and too impractical to implement. Approximation algorithms are frequently easier to implement and far better in practice. A better survey of non-approximate results: https://www2.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall08/cps234/projects/sayan_proj.pdf